# Magento2 exam difference between online and onsite proctored?

Tags: magento2, certification

I want to know what is the difference between **online and onsite proctored exam**.

Anyone put light on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggests, in the **`online proctored exam`**, you are allowed to take the exam online from your place. But in that case, there are some pre-conditions which you need to fulfill.

In the **`onsite proctored exam`**, you need to appear for the exam at the pre-qualified test centers, which have all the pre-conditions satisfied.

If you have all required resources available and you can arrange those resources as per the conditions asked by Magento, it is better to take Online Proctored Exam (in my opinion).

Below are the conditions which you need to satisfy if you are planning for the **online proctored exam**.

- A PC with Windows or MacOS and admin rights
- Adobe Flash
- A webcam which is not built-in so you can arrange it freely
- A microphone (can be built into the webcam or the laptop)
- A fast internet connection with at least 1 Mbit/s upload and download
  Only one screen
- An undisturbed location with some space

To know about the experience of the online proctored exam, please visit:
https://mageside.com/blog/magento-2-certification-online

**Update:**

1) Please check the complete checklist below for preparing online proctored test environment:
https://www.kryteriononline.com/docs/PreparingForYourExam.pdf

2) How it works blogpost: https://www.integer-net.com/the-magento-2-online-certification-how-it-works/

Answer (score 1):

**Onsite Proctored** : Take exam by exam center

Testing centers set their own schedules for when Magento certification exams are offered, so availability can vary greatly among testing centers. Typically, exam registration is required at least 24-72 hours in advance; however, it’s recommended that you register one week in advance to ensure your preferred date and time is available.

**Online Proctoring Process** : Take exam by home/office

Online proctored exams are delivered through Kryterion’s Sentinel Secure software. You will be required to download the Sentinel Secure software and create a biometric profile to validate your identity before your scheduled exam time. Additionally, online proctoring requires an external, stand-alone webcam; internal built-in webcams are not accepted.

Comment: you have mentioned Salesforce certification instead of Magento certification. Please fix the typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

How will we take exam in Onsite Proctored. will we write answer in paper or should i use laptop?